# Is there a Devise callback for "You are already signed in."?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, callback

When I revisit `/users/sign_in` after already being signed in, I see the flash `You are already signed in.` and the following in my logs..

```
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

..and I get redirected to `/`. I would like to call a callback and redirect differently depending on some condition.

This is similar in spirit to `after_sign_up_path_for` except it's more like "after trying sign in when already signed in".

Answer (score 6):

Right now, there's no easy way to accomplish what you want. (Maybe a pull request is in order.)

The problem is that [when the user is already authenticated](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3d9dea39b2978e3168604ccda956fb6ec17c5e27/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb#L110), Devise calls the [`after_sign_in_path_for`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3d9dea39b2978e3168604ccda956fb6ec17c5e27/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L142-L144) method.

This method is also called when the user logins normally, so even if you override this method, there's no way to distinguish between users who just logged in and those who were already logged in.

The only solution is to extend/override Devise's SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  private

  def require_no_authentication
    assert_is_devise_resource!
    return unless is_navigational_format?
    no_input = devise_mapping.no_input_strategies

    authenticated = if no_input.present?
      args = no_input.dup.push scope: resource_name
      warden.authenticate?(*args)
    else
      warden.authenticated?(resource_name)
    end

    if authenticated && resource = warden.user(resource_name)
      flash[:alert] = I18n.t("devise.failure.already_authenticated")
      redirect_to YOUR_PATH_HERE
    end
  end
end
```

Since this controller inherits from Devise's, when an action isn't defined in your controller that action will be processed by Devise's controller. So you only have to override that `require_no_authentication` method, which [is called in a before_filter](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/3d9dea39b2978e3168604ccda956fb6ec17c5e27/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L2).

Finally, edit your routes file so this change takes effect:

```
# routes.rb
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :sessions => 'sessions' }
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to make sure that the original functionality is preserved is to copy the entire method definition and change parts of it.

```
def require_no_authentication
  assert_is_devise_resource!
  return unless is_navigational_format?
  no_input = devise_mapping.no_input_strategies

  authenticated = if no_input.present?
    args = no_input.dup.push scope: resource_name
    warden.authenticate?(*args)
  else
    warden.authenticated?(resource_name)
  end

  if authenticated && resource = warden.user(resource_name)
    # CHANGE THE FOLLOWING LINES AS NEEDED  
    flash[:alert] = I18n.t("devise.failure.already_authenticated")
    redirect_to after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end
end
```